# Google Maps API local search returns only 4 results?

Tags: google-maps

In the code sample code here
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#the_hello_world_of_local_search

I can't see any parameter that limits to 4 so why does it returns only 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setSearchResult:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GSearch